# Write protocol headers in little endian to wire - Clean approach in Java?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, network-protocols

I'm experimenting with the [QUIC example server](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WJvyZflAO2pq77yOLbp9NsGjC1CHetAXV8I0fQe-B_U/edit) from the Chromium project, as I'm trying to implement a simple Java client which speaks QUIC.

How would you program the header fields (QUIC is defined in Little-Endian)? I'm throwing around byte-arrays and bitwise operators but it feels there should be a lot cleaner way to do this. 
Any libraries which allow me to set certain bits in a header and stuff like that?

Greetings

Comment: ByteBuffer has some methods to help with endian conversion. And Apache Commons IO has an EndianUtils class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `ByteBuffer` and define it to be little-endian:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ...
buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
```

Then you can call `putInt(value)` to put integer values using the byte ordering you want and later retrieve the bytes and send them on their merry way.

Comment: Thank you, your answer put me on the right path. An alternative is ByteBuf from the Netty project.

Comment: @Shady - I'm not too familiar with Netty, but I imagine that they have lots of useful tools for this kind of thing.